# Want to replace a Id value in a column in data in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a parameter like

```
@strbody=id:XXX sub:YYY asd:ZZZ date1:1611031729 date2:1611031729
```

I want to use a SQL command to replace only the ID value in @strbody.

Can anyone help me on the same.

Comment: Please write further information about this replacing

Comment: Original value @strbody=id:XXX sub:YYY asd:ZZZ date1:1611031729 date2:1611031729

Comment: Yes, and your replacing? Write the desired result and a query about your trial

Comment: Original value @strbody=id:XXX sub:YYY asd:ZZZ date1:1611031729 date2:1611031729  I want to replace with the data in other coloumn @newid              Example @strbody=id:@newid sub:YYY asd:ZZZ date1:1611031729 date2:1611031729

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
@strbody = CONCAT('id:', @newid, SUBSTRING(@strbody, LOCATE('sub:', @strbody)));
```

Comment: I am getting response as 'LOCATE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you on?